# reCAPTCHA for C++ server

Tags: c++, recaptcha

I am not able to find any recaptcha support for c++ at http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/

how can I use it in my c++ server code ?

if not is there any other captcha which I can use in c++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recapcha API for using it in C++.

for eg:

[Recapcha validation API](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html)

And These API are not bounded to any specific language.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any relevant code either, so I wrote my own, which I am happy to share - see http://trumphurst.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/using-recaptcha-from-c.html